# Project: Create a java webapp in Vaadin (to-do-list)

Tags: java, vaadin

To improve my programming skills I would like to set up a little project for my work. I would like to create a kind of to do list, with several columns (Note, PO Order, Shipping, Done (as a Checkbox), ect.).

At the end of a day, I want to be able to click on the checkbox for every row which is done and save them in a data file. Also I would like to create this as a web application, running on the server in the company.

Since I would like to improve especially my java skills I would like to do this (if possible) mostly in java and to get in touch with frameworks, so I started to read about [*Vaadin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin).

My question is, if you guys could give maybe some experience about a project like this and if it's in general possible to realise this with Vaadin.

Comment: Yes it's possible

Comment: Unfortunately, such a question is very broad and opinion-soliciting. There's no specific programming question here; rather, a general discussion around a particular framework (and Stack Overflow doesn't support such discussions). Please edit your question to contain a specific question, as you work through your to-do app.

Comment: @cfrick - Please don't post such comments. They aren't helpful, and can be seen as condescending & patronizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To improve my programming skills

If you want to build web apps using pure Java on the server-side, Vaadin fits the bill.

You describe the layout and widgets you want to appear in the user interface using Java code. Then, at runtime, Vaadin automatically generates the necessary HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, AJAX, WebSocket, and Push code needed to render that UI on the client-side in the user’s web browser.

The beautiful part is that you get all the benefits of using those web standards technologies without having to learn them or code them.

> create a kind of to do list, with several columns (Note, PO Order, Shipping, Done (as a Checkbox), ect.).

Vaadin provides a powerful and well-designed data-grid widget, Vaadin Grid, that can display such columns including the checkbox.

> I want to be able to click on the checkbox for every row

The Vaadin Grid tool has an interactive mode that allows the user to directly edit the row, including clicking on the checkbox.

You could alternatively let the user select several rows and click a button (that you programmed) than would mark them as done, checking the checkboxes of the group at once.

Also, Grid has a built-in feature where it displays a column of checkboxes to be clicked en masse as an alternative to selecting rows. This helps the many users who are not adept at maneuvering through a multi-row selection with mouse-and-keyboard gestures.

> I would like to create this as a web application, running on the server in the company.

Your Vaadin-based web app is built on standard Java Servlet technology. So you can deploy to your choice of any of a dozen or more web containers such as Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, Glassfish, Wildfly, and many more.

> I would like to do this (if possible) mostly in java

You can build your web app entirely with Java code by using Vaadin. All Java on the server-side, no Java on the client-side.

You may eventually want to learn a bit of CSS to tweak the fonts and colors and such. But this is optional.

> if it's in general possible to realise this with Vaadin.

Indeed, this project sounds like an ideal match to Vaadin.

In contrast, where Vaadin is contraindicated would be:

- For web sites with crazy complicated layouts such as slick magazine sites. Vaadin is aimed at business-oriented data-entry apps.
- For programmers who *want* to grapple directly with the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. rather than avoid it.